# How to hide an element when clicking in another element who shares the same classes in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, dom-events

I have created a toggle menu using **vanilla javaScript** because I am trying **not to use jQuery** as a dependency. I have been successful so far, but I want to toggle off the visibility of the other elements when clicking & opening a menu content.

**HTML code for the markup**:

```
<div class="menu-link">Menu 1</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>

<br>

<div class="menu-link">Menu 2</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>

<br>

<div class="menu-link">Menu 3</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>

<br>

<div class="menu-link">Menu 4</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>
```

**CSS code for the styling of the toggle on/off effect of the menu content:**

```
menu-link {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu-content {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-name: show;
    animation-name: show;
}

/* Show Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes show {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes show {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
    animation-duration: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

**JavaScript code to toggle class on/off:**

```
// var declaration
var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');

// Loop through the array & add a click event to toggle "show" class
for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++ ) {
    menuLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(this.nextElementSibling.className.match("show") ) {
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
        } else {
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
        }
    });
};
```

This is [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wpvqoz6g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide other elements in the DOM for this purpose. One way to do it:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o81g5r9/)

```
// var declaration
var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');

// Loop through the array & add a click event to toggle "show" class
for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++ ) {
    var el = menuLinks[i]
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var itemId = i;

      var allMenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');

    if(this.nextElementSibling.className.match("show") ) {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
    }

    for(var j=0; j<allMenuLinks.length; j++) {
        if(this==allMenuLinks[j]) {
        continue;
      }
      allMenuLinks[j].nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
You can simply get reference to the element which was clicked directly on your event listener and change visibility of all elements but the one which was clicked.

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++ ) {
  menuLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const clickedElement = event.target;
    // remove show class from all elements but clicked element
    menuLinks.forEach(function(linkEl) {
      if (linkEl !== clickedElement) {
        linkEl.classList.toggle("show", false);
      } else {
        linkEl.classList.toggle("show", true);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

One problem I see here is that you are registering click listners on all the elements. You can optimize that by adding one click listener to a parent DOM node instead on each individual node.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the callback function you could loop through your array **menuLinks**, remove the show class from all siblings and finally add it to the sibling which parent fired the click event.
Something like:

```js
// var declaration
var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');

// Loop through the array & add a click event to toggle "show" class
for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++) {
  menuLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    for (var a = 0; a < menuLinks.length; a++) {
      if (menuLinks[a] != e.target) {
        menuLinks[a].nextElementSibling.className = "menu-content animated";
      }

    }
    e.target.nextElementSibling.className = "show";
  });
};
```

```css
menu-link {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu-content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Show Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.show {
  -webkit-animation-name: show;
  animation-name: show;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-link">Menu 1</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>

<br>

<div class="menu-link">Menu 2</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>

<br>

<div class="menu-link">Menu 3</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>

<br>

<div class="menu-link">Menu 4</div>

<p class="menu-content animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas odio facere sunt ullam quo ex amet sint in vitae.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are creating a new function each time in loop so you should rather declare such function outside. The whole code might look like this:

```
var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link');
var onClick = function () {
  var target = this;
  for (var i = 0, j = menuLinks.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (target === menuLinks[i]) {
      target.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      target.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
};
// Loop through the array & add a click event to toggle "show" class
for (var i = 0, j = menuLinks.length; i < j; i++) {
    menuLinks[i].addEventListener('click', onClick);
}
```